# In ElasticSearch is there any API through which I can create a rule in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, security, postman, kibana

In Elasticsearch is there any API through which I can create a rule in Kibana. And Using postman API testing software, how can I perform the operations in it for creating a rule. If there is a pre-existing API in Elasticsearch please mention it in the answer

Answer (score 0):

## Tldr;

No there is not API in elasticsearch to create a rule.

BUT there is an [API in Kibana that exist](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/create-rule-api.html) for this use case.

## Solution

Create an index threshold rule that has actions associated with a server log connector:

```json
POST api/alerting/rule
{
  "params":{
      "aggType":"avg",
      "termSize":6,
      "thresholdComparator":">",
      "timeWindowSize":5,
      "timeWindowUnit":"m",
      "groupBy":"top",
      "threshold":[
         1000
      ],
      "index":[
         ".test-index"
      ],
      "timeField":"@timestamp",
      "aggField":"sheet.version",
      "termField":"name.keyword"
   },
   "consumer":"alerts",
   "rule_type_id":".index-threshold",
   "schedule":{
      "interval":"1m"
   },
   "actions":[
      {
         "id":"dceeb5d0-6b41-11eb-802b-85b0c1bc8ba2",
         "group":"threshold met",
         "params":{
            "level":"info",
            "message":"alert '{{alertName}}' is active for group '{{context.group}}':\n\n- Value: {{context.value}}\n- Conditions Met: {{context.conditions}} over {{params.timeWindowSize}}{{params.timeWindowUnit}}\n- Timestamp: {{context.date}}"
         }
      }
   ],
   "tags":[
      "cpu"
   ],
   "notify_when":"onActionGroupChange",
   "name":"my alert"
}
```